# how to add css in html element by its arrtibute (not ID not Class)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**I need to get a display none the above span by attribute "data-email".**

```
<span contenteditable="false" id="signature1596021675154" tabindex="1" data-role="test" data-email="qwerty" title="qwerty" data-name="name" style="z-index: 600; margin-right: 0px; visibility: visible;" class="index signature-container editor-elements valid_button"> </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [attribute] selector is used to select elements with a specified attribute.

in your css you can do that:

```
span[data-mail] {
 display: none;
}
```

or

```
span[data-mail="qwerty"] {
 display: none;
}
```

```css
span[data-email]{
  color: red
}

span[data-email="test"]{
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="false" id="signature1596021675154" tabindex="1" data-role="test" data-email="qwerty" title="qwerty" data-name="name" style="z-index: 600; margin-right: 0px; visibility: visible;" class="index signature-container editor-elements valid_button">hello </span>

<span data-email="test">world</span>
```

Comment: not working above code

Comment: @SagarDhiman can you elaborate ? Why do you say it's not working ? If you click on `Run code snippet` you should see that it works indeed !

Answer (score 0):

Just select element by attribute and apply CSS.

```js
$('span[data-email="qwerty"]').css({
  display: "none"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span contenteditable="false" id="signature1596021675154" tabindex="1" data-role="test" data-email="qwerty" title="qwerty" data-name="name" style="z-index: 600; margin-right: 0px; visibility: visible;" class="index signature-container editor-elements valid_button">Some text</span>
```

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Because its HTML data attribute you can do the following in javascript

```
email_condition = "qwerty"; //you can set whatever condition you need
console.log(document.querySelector(`span[data-email="${email_condition}"]`));
document
  .querySelector(`span[data-email="${email_condition}"]`)
  .classList.add("display_none");
```

display_none is a class  defined in css whose definition looks like

```
.display_none {
  display: none;
}
```

You can refer my [codepen link]:https://codepen.io/ankitt8/pen/pogXJJV

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-* 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

As mentioned in the comment if you want to make the code work for multiple span tags with same email condition you can do as below

```
email_condition = "qwerty";
let allSpanEmailTag = document.querySelectorAll(
  `span[data-email="${email_condition}"]`
);
// note its querySelectorAll previously it was querySelector only
// querySelectorAll returns a list of node based on specified condition.
for (let i = 0; i < allSpanEmailTag.length; ++i) {
  allSpanEmailTag[i].classList.add("display_none");
}
```

The codepen link has been updated so you can refer that!

Comment: about code is working for only for single span, but in my case their is multiple span of same condition